# how to combine two passes in the compositor and get this result in proper way

Tags: compositing-nodes

I'm trying to get this result in the compositor but it gives me that ugly aliasing, I don't know what is the proper way to combine them.   [image: i want the same result without aliasing or black line]

[blend file](https://mega.nz/file/3RUGiKhT#bhJnAfNxkpcze8EFdnXaU8sCtXmf95yzLAw8Lub638M)

thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome! What do you would like to combine and why?

Comment: Not all the render passes are antialiased, why do you need that particular pass?

Comment: i am using color dodge to make a mask to separate glossy indirect, i need only glossy indirect on the floor to get my sphere and reflecction with a white background

Comment: i think my problem is using dodge color to separate glossy indirect, i need to convert glossy indirect in a mask, maybe converting black parts of the glossy pass in alpha